# get custom data from anchor tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I'm trying to obtain this value for a javscript function

```
<a href="#" id="like" name="like" data-value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?> " onclick="like(); return false;">
                <img src="<?php echo $ROOT. "/assets/images/templates/like.png"?>" class="aligncenter" alt="" /></a>
```

I'd like to get the id which is the data-value.

I've tried using jquery selectors such as `var id = $('a[data-value]').attr();`but obviously have it wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plain JavaScript has 2 Variants: [getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getAttribute) and [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset):

```
var el = document.getElementById( 'like' );
el.getAttribute( 'data-value' ); 
el.dataset.value;
```

As you tagged this with jQuery as well, you could use [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or  [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$( '#like' ).data( 'value' );
$( '#like' ).attr( 'data-value' );
```

Using `data()` you can only read the value, but not update it! `data()` refers to a jQuery data object, which is just initialized with `data-` fields of the HTML element, but does not update them!

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's `data()` will get the data attribute (but not set it) :

```
var id = $('#like').data('value');
```

or plain JS

```
var id = document.getElementById('like').getAttribute('data-value');
```

Answer (score 3):

use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
var id= $('#like').data('value');
```

> .data() Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `data` to retrieve a data attribute:

```
var id = $('a[data-value]').data('value');
```

Or, given that the `a` element has an `id`:

```
var id = $('#like').data('value');
```

You can use `attr()`, but note this will only get `data` attributes which are attached to the DOM element and as such is not considered good practice. Data attributes added using jQuery will only appear in the data cache and available through `data()` so cannot be retrieved in this way:

```
var id = $('#like').attr('data-value');
```